# Groovy catch a parent Exception but NOT a children Exception

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, try-catch, jenkins-groovy, rethrow

*(context: integrating with an application -Jenkins- with various plugins not all with good design)*

I have these exception:

```
public class AbortException extends IOException
```

and in some cases I want to catch IOException but avoid catching the AbortException

Which one is more correct?

```
try {
...
} catch (AbortException e) {
    throw e //this failure should fail
} catch (IOException e) {
    [handle this]
}
```

or

```
try {
...
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (e instanceof AbortException)
        throw e //this failure should fail
    else
        [handle this]
}
```

I am unsure if in the first case the second catch block would intercept the re-thrown AbortException

Comment: Both will do what you're looking for, but the first one is the native way to do it. The second catch block won't catch anything that is not in the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks @ernest_k, I actually wrote a quick test and yes, they both do it, so I'll keep #1 as it's easier to read